# Android Studio 3.0 Warning: Using incompatible plugins for the annotation processing

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, warnings

After update Android Studio to 3.0 version I have warning:

```
Error:android-apt plugin is incompatible with the Android Gradle plugin.  Please use 'annotationProcessor' configuration instead.
```

I tried to rewrite my gradle source ,but I still have a warning.
Here is a source

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:0.89.+'
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}




apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.syncapp"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.11'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.1'
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'

compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:mockwebserver:2.7.5'

compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.4'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.4'


}
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

As you can see,in my project I'm using butterknife,dagger,okhttp,retrofit2 and     eventbus support libraries

Any solution? I can't run my app
Thanks

Comment: try to change all your `compile` to `implementation`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you have a look at this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#annotationProcessor_config)?

Basically:

> If you are experiencing issues migrating to the new dependency resolution >strategy, you can restore behavior to that of Android plugin 2.3.0 by setting >includeCompileClasspath true.

```
android {
...
defaultConfig {
    ...
    javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
            includeCompileClasspath false
        }
    }
}
}
```

then you can opt to remove the Apt plugin to make the project cleaner but consider that should not affect according to the official documentation

> android-apt plugin users: This behavior change currently does not affect the >android-apt plugin. However, the plugin will not be compatible with future >versions of the Android plugin for Gradle
>   Also when yuo migrate to Android Studio 3.0 you should not use compile but implementation for every dependency

What also you should do is to try to upgrade or downgrade the annotation processor dependecies you have with Dagger or Butterknife, if does not work try to remove Butterknife(but I am not sure about that if the Dagger one is enough, anyway you should not need).

Comment: Thanks your attention.I added javaCompileOptions in gradle,but still have a problem.any solution ? @trocchietto

Comment: try also to update  or downgrade the dagger and butterknife dependencies!

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.
> Conflict with dependency 'junit:junit' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (4.11) and test app (4.12) differ. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for details. @trocchietto

Comment: good so my solution worked! the error you are getting now is another issue, a really easy  one to solve.  your question problem has been solved. Please accept/upvote my answer. If you cannot solve the new bug can help you in chat

Comment: @Baggio ok I tell you directly : testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.11' have to changed to 4.12

Comment: Here is a solution.I answer  myself  compile 'junit:junit:4.12' @trocchietto

Comment: Thank dude @trocchietto

Answer (score 2):

Remove `apt` plugin from your `build.gradle` file. And wherever in dependency you are using `apt` replace it with `annotationProcessor`. Moreover update your `realm` dependency version to `4.1.1`  as well.

Comment: I updated realm verion,but where I use apt plugin in build.gradle file? I posted all source @Newbie

Comment: My bad, there is no use of apt. Did issue still persists after update realm version?. Morever, check in submodules(if any) build.gradle file for apt.

Comment: Yes still @Newbie